# swift 2 Applying the same background in different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, background, swift2, ios9, viewcontroller

I've got 4+ Viewcontrollers all with the same class. when i add the background in `Viewcontroller.swift` it only applies to one view controller. `

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {`
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg")!)
    }
```

All my view controllers have different Storyboard ID so maybe i call on these and apply then background  then. how do i apply the same background on all my view controllers without remaining them. any advise is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate, add this line:

```
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]]
```

And then in all the Views, just set this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```